# Why does Enum.Parse create undefined entries?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, behavior

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string value = "12345";
        Type enumType = typeof(Fruits);
        Fruits fruit = Fruits.Apple;
        try
        {
            fruit = (Fruits) Enum.Parse(enumType, value);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} is no healthy food.", value));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("You should eat at least one {0} per day.", fruit));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public enum Fruits
    {
        Apple,
        Banana,
        Orange
    }
}
```

If you execute the code above the result shows:

> You should eat at least one 12345 per day.

I really expected an ArgumentException to be thrown if a unknown name (string) is passed. Taking a close look at the Enum.Parse definition reveals:

> **Summary:**
> Converts the string representation of the name or **numeric value** of one or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object.
>
> **Exceptions:**
> *ArgumentException*:  enumType is not an Enum. -or- value is either an empty string or only contains white space. -or- **value is a name, but not one of the named constants defined for the enumeration**.

I.e. if a string representation of an integer is passed, a new enum value is created and now exception is thrown by design. Does this make sense?

At least I now know to call  `Enum.IsDefined(enumType, value)` prior to `Enum.Parse()`

Comment: Why are you asking and answering your own question?

Comment: The question is asked on the behavior...

Comment: hopefully I've explained the behaviour (or my interpretation of it *anyway*) in my answer in a way that makes sense. If it doesn't let me know and I'll see what I can do to address that =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "named constant" is the textual representation of an Enum's value, not the number that you've assigned to it.

If you change:

```
string value = "12345";
```

To:

```
string value = "Cake";
```

You'll see the error you're expecting, because "value is a name, but not one of the named constants defined for the enumeration.". In this instance the value you're passing in *is* a name, "Cake", but not one in the enumeration.

Think of `Enum.Parse(enumType, value);` doing the following:

1. If `value` is a null reference, throw an ArgumentNullException
2. Is the value in `value` one of the named constants in the enumeration in `enumType`. If yes, return that value from the enumeration and stop.
3. Is the value in `value` directly convertible to the underlying type (in this instance Int32), if yes, return that value and stop (**even if there's no named constant for that value**).
4. Is the value in `value` directly convertible to the underlying type, but outside of the range of the underlying type? e.g. the value is a string containing a number one greater than MAXINT. If yes, throw an `OverflowException`.
5. Is the value not castable to the underlying type? If yes, throw an ArgumentException.

Comment: You are right, as Enum is a Int32 Enum.Parse("<integer representation>") is correct in returning a valid value. My problem was caused by seeing Enum as a constricted Int32 which it is in fact not.

Comment: This is not, strictly speaking, correct. A string is never "castable" to an int, it requires a conversion that's possible through a variety of methods (`Convert.ToInt32`, `int.Parse`, `int.TryParse`, etc.). A more accurate expression of 3.) would be "Is the value in `value` directly *convertible* to the underlying type (in this instance `Int32`)? If yes, return that value and stop (**even if there's no named constant for that value**).

Answer (score 4):

An enum can be any value of its base integer type.  It is not just restricted to named constants.

For instance, the following is perfectly valid:

```
enum Foo{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
}

Foo x = (Foo)5;
```

Even though 5 does not correspond to a named constant, it is still a valid value for `Foo`, since the underlying type for `Foo` is `Int32`.

If one were to call `x.ToString()`, the returned value would be simply "5", since no named constant corresponds with x's value.

`Enum.Parse()` is the converse function of `Enum.ToString()`.  You should expect that whatever `Enum.ToString()` can return that `Enum.Parse()` can accept.  This includes, for instance, comma-separated values for flags enums:

```
[Flags]
enum Foo{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 4,
    D = 8
}

Foo x = Foo.A | Foo.B | Foo.C | Foo.D;
int i = (int)x;
string s = x.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(i);
Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.WriteLine((Foo)Enum.Parse(typeof(Foo), i.ToString()) == x);
Console.WriteLine((Foo)Enum.Parse(typeof(Foo), s) == x);
```

Output:

```
15
A, B, C, D
True
True
```

**EDIT:**

What you really seem to want is something like this:

```
static Enum GetEnumValue(Type enumType, string name){
    // null-checking omitted for brevity

    int index = Array.IndexOf(Enum.GetNames(enumType), name);
    if(index < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("\"" + name + "\" is not a value in " + enumType, "name");

    return Enum.GetValues(enumType).GetValue(index);
}
```

or a case-insensitive version:

```
static Enum GetEnumValue(Type enumType, string name, bool ignoreCase){
    // null-checking omitted

    int index;
    if(ignoreCase)
        index = Array.FindIndex(Enum.GetNames(enumType),
            s => string.Compare(s, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
            // or StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase or something if you
            // need to support fancy Unicode names
    else index = Array.IndexOf(Enum.GetNames(enumType), name);

    if(index < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("\"" + name + "\" is not a value in " + enumType, "name");

    return Enum.GetValues(enumType).GetValue(index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional insight on `Enum.Parse()` and `ToString()`, I did not know about the feature with comma-separated values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Enum.IsDefined:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx

```
using System;

    [Flags] enum Colors { None=0, Red = 1, Green = 2, Blue = 4 };

    public class Example
    {
       public static void Main()
       {
          string[] colorStrings = { "0", "2", "8", "blue", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red, Green" };
          foreach (string colorString in colorStrings)
          {
             try {
                Colors colorValue = (Colors) Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), colorString);        
                if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Colors), colorValue) | colorValue.ToString().Contains(","))  
                   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", colorString, colorValue.ToString());
                else
                   Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an underlying value of the Colors enumeration.", colorString);
             }
             catch (ArgumentException) {
                Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not a member of the Colors enumeration.", colorString);
             }
          }
       }
    }
    // The example displays the following output:
    //       Converted '0' to None.
    //       Converted '2' to Green.
    //       8 is not an underlying value of the Colors enumeration.
    //       'blue' is not a member of the Colors enumeration.
    //       Converted 'Blue' to Blue.
    //       'Yellow' is not a member of the Colors enumeration.
    //       Converted 'Red, Green' to Red, Green.
```

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't understand why Enum.Parse generates new values, it's like calling Int.Parse("big number not known to mankind") and getting a result...

Answer (score 0):

I personally think it's a pity that `Enum.Parse` accepts the string representation of a number. If you're looking for an alternative, you might want to look at my [Unconstrained Melody](http://unconstrained-melody.googlecode.com) project which has various parsing options, and is strongly typed too.

You certainly *can* use `Enum.IsDefined` in conjunction with parsing. Do you definitely *want* to accept string versions of numbers though? Or are you really only expecting names?

Comment: Is it really a pity that `Enum.Parse` accepts the string representation of a number?  I would consider it broken if it didn't, because it would mean that an enum value might not round trip to and from a string, i.e. `Enum.Parse(enumValue.ToString())` could fail.