# C# enum array accepting a wrong value

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I was working on a web service method that will receive an array of ints as parameter, and then, inside the method, I converted the values in the array into enum values, and stored them in a enum list. However, when a value that's not in the enum is passed, it is added to the enum list with no problems. No `InvalidCastException`, nothing. I made a test project that looks like this:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TestValues> values = new List<TestValues>() {
            TestValues.Value1,
            TestValues.Value2,
            (TestValues)15
        };

        foreach (var val in values)
            Console.WriteLine(val);

        Console.Read();
    }

    enum TestValues
    { 
        Value1 = 2,
        Value2 = 4,
        Value3 = 8
    }
}
```

When I run it, the output is:

```
Value1
Value2
15
```

For my web service, I'll implement a validation, so this will never hapen at all. But... this is weird! Shouldn't the runtime throw a `InvalidCastException`  or `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, or something similar? Since I got a list of enums (and not int values), I want the values to be limitted to the values of the enum (that's what an enum is for).

Am I missing something? Is this a .NET bug, a C# bug or is there something I don't know with enums?

Comment: Read this one:
[Why does casting int to invalid enum value NOT throw exception?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413804/why-does-casting-int-to-invalid-enum-value-not-throw-exception

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can assign any value to an `enum` that the underlying type allows. By default, the underlying type is `int`, so you can assign any `int` value to the `enum`.

The main reason for this is because if you have a `[Flags]` enumeration, you *want* to be able to assign composite values:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyFlags
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2
}

MyFlags flags = (MyFlags)3; // Equivalent to setting A and B
```

Preferably you'd just use the enumeration values to do that, though:

```
MyFlags flags = MyFlags.A | MyFlags.B; // Sets flags to 3
```

It's important to note, of course, that the `[Flags]` attribute isn't required to enable this assignment. All `enum`s have this property, by design.

As pointed out by a number of people, you can use `Enum.IsDefined()` to determine if a particular value is valid for a given `enum`. That should help with your validation.

Comment: I completly forgot about `[Flags]`, for I rarely use it. To me, it seems like a clear advantage for that use, but a little odd for the more common use of enums. By the way, the comments and the other answers provide nice complementary links to the subject.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is no check for defined values when you convert to an enum value.

You can use the `IsDefined` method to check if a specific value is defined:

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TestValues), value)) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always cast any int value to an enum based on int. This is by design, as the cast would be a lot slower if it had to check all legal values.

Comment: I don't think speed was the deciding factor here.

Comment: @Henk - please do elaborate, are there any other factors besides Flags?

Answer (score 1):

To determine if the specified `int` is defined within the `enum` you can use [Enum.IsDefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx).

```
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TestValues), 15);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read the following thread:

[Why does Enum.Parse create undefined entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575176/why-does-enum-parse-create-undefined-entries)

In short, this is valid.  If you want to check if the value is defined, use  `Enum.IsDefined`.